# Solving an equation for rational modulus 1

Tags: equation-solving, modular-arithmetic

I want to solve an system of equations of the form 
$$\prod_{i=1}^n  x_i^{M_{i,k}}=1 \qquad k=1,\ldots,n$$
with complex $x_i$ with constraint $|x_i|=1$ and
 $M_{i,k}$  integers. 
This is basically a system of polynomial equation and I can just use Solve over the complexes. Is this efficient? My equations are in `Eq[1]`,... `Eq[n]`, e.g. 
`Eq[1]={x[2] x[3]^3 == x[2]^3}` and my code is

```
And @@ Array[Eq, {m - 1}]
Solve[%, Table[x[i], {i, 2, R}], Complexes]
```

Wouldn't it be better to solve the following linear system?
Because $\{x_i:i=1,\ldots,n\}$ are roots of unity
this can be made into a linear system with $x_i = \exp(2\pi i h_i)$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n M_{i,k} h_i=0 \qquad k=1,\ldots,n
$$
where $h_i\in \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$. It seems to be much more efficient to solve the linear system over the $\mathbb Q /\mathbb Z$. Has Mathematica something like this built in?

Unfortunately, I can just find how to solve such linear equations in $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$. If I knew a common divisor $N$ of the solution I could also multiply by $N$ and solve it over an integer $\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z$

Comment: Hi, welcome to Mathematica.SE, please consider taking the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) so you learn the basic rules of the site. Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e. its about mathematics and not Mathematica. If that's not the case, please [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make it explicitly about Mathematica programming. Include a minimum example of the code you are working on.

Comment: Yes, taking logs to make it linear would be better. But where do you get the constraint that these must be roots of unity?

Comment: This are the only solutions I am interested in, in the particular equations I have, the only solutions are roots of unity or 0. I will edit the post.

Comment: If you post a representative example you are more likely to get a viable response.